# Port from MSVS2005 to MSVS2010: I canno longer find ReadProcessorPwrScheme()

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-c++

I'm currently porting code from MSVS2005 to MSVS2010. I have a problem with the function ReadProcessorPwrScheme() (and also WriteProcessorPwrScheme()) that no longer exist.

I looked at the file Powrprof.h to find:

```
#if (NTDDI_VERSION >= NTDDI_WINXP)
//
// deprecated.
//
STDAPI_(BOOLEAN)
ReadProcessorPwrScheme(
    __in UINT uiID,
    __out PMACHINE_PROCESSOR_POWER_POLICY pMachineProcessorPowerPolicy
    );
#endif
```

and the same for the `write` function.

1) It compiled correctly with MSVS2005 but I saw that the SDK changed (just taking a look at the file Powrprof.h and we see that they differ. In the file with MSVS2005, there was no conditional compilation.)

**Note that if you want me to tell you which SDK is used you will have to tell me where to find the version number!**

2) I'm on Win7 SP1, 64 bits.

Is there a workaround, replacement functions, or whatever that could help me?

Thank you!
Dominique

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[The documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa373190.aspx) tells you what's going on:

> [`ReadProcessorPwrScheme` is available for use in the operating systems specified in the Requirements section. It may be altered or unavailable in subsequent versions. See Remarks.]

Remarks:

> Starting with Windows Vista, power management configuration of the system's processor is controlled through the GUID_PROCESSOR_SETTINGS_SUBGROUP power settings subgroup. Use the [`PowerEnumerate`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa372730.aspx) function to enumerate individual settings.